# How to test Luigi with FakeS3?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, luigi, fakes3

I'm trying to test my [Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) pipelines inside a vagrant machine using [FakeS3](https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3) to simulate my S3 endpoints. For [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) to be able to interact with FakeS3 the connection must be setup with the `OrdinaryCallingFormat` as in:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection, OrdinaryCallingFormat
conn = S3Connection('XXX', 'XXX', is_secure=False, 
                    port=4567, host='localhost',
                    calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat())
```

but when using Luigi this connection is buried in the [s3 module](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/luigi/s3.py#L111-L114). I was able to pass most of the options by modifying my `luigi.cfg` and adding an s3 section as in

```
[s3]
host=127.0.0.1
port=4567
aws_access_key_id=XXX
aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXX
is_secure=0
```

but I don't know how to pass the required object for the `calling_format`.

Now I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed. Options I can think of:

1. Figure out how to pass the `OrdinaryCallingFormat` to `S3Connection` through `luigi.cfg`
2. Figure out how to force `boto` to always use this calling format in my Vagrant machine, by setting an unknown option to me either in `.aws/config` or `boto.cfg`
3. Make `FakeS3` to accept the default `calling_format` used by `boto` that happens to be `SubdomainCallingFormat` (whatever it means).

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not pass it into the constructor as kwargs for the S3Client?

```
client = S3Client(aws_access_key, aws_secret_key,
                  {'calling_format':OrdinaryCallingFormat()})
target = S3Target('s3://somebucket/test', client=client)
```

Comment: I could but this line of code is in luigi not in my code. Patching luigi is the workaround but would break with any new version of Luigi

Comment: you are not instantiating the `S3Target` in your code? You should be able to pass the `S3Client` above to your `S3Target` constructor as the client parameter.

Comment: I'm instantiating the S3Target but then I cannot find an elegant way for the Luigi pipeline to inject the S3Client for FakeS3 and the default S3Client for production. Any ideas about how to do this dependency injection without polluting all code for the pipelines?

Comment: I guess if you want to do it once, you would do something like a S3ClientFactory that could create the fakeone or the real one, and then use some sort of config setting to know whether you are in production.

Answer (score 0):

I did not encounter any problem when using boto3 connect to fakeS3.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client(
    "s3", region_name="fakes3",
    use_ssl=False,
    aws_access_key_id="",
    aws_secret_access_key="",
    endpoint_url="http://localhost:4567"
)
```

no specially calling method required.

Perhaps I am wrong that you really need OrdinaryCallingFormat, If my code doesn't work, please go through the github topic boto3 support on : 
https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/334

Comment: The problem is the combination Luigi+FakeS3

Answer (score 0):

You can set it with the `calling_format` parameter. Here is a configuration example for fake-s3:

```
[s3]
aws_access_key_id=123
aws_secret_access_key=abc
host=fake-s3
port=4569
is_secure=0
calling_format=boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat
```